# Extjs 4.1.1 - print/export the whole grid

Tags: printing, export-to-excel, extjs4.1

Is there any way to export a whole grid to excel sheet or send it to print, with all pages ? I couldn't find what I need in documentation.

Comment: All pages? Its a buffered or paginated grid?

Comment: Buffered scrolling grid. I thought it will be easier to print/export

Comment: No, its not, because you don't know if all your data its on the client... You can, of course, export the visible part of the grid ( + buffered data) but i don't think thats good, what i do in that case is make a server exporter wich takes the same query used by the grid but ignores pagination, so it gets all the results and then build the Excel XML server-side.

Comment: Clientside export will also not work for IE due to setted restrictions of MS. So a serverside solution will be the only one that is cross-browser save

Comment: to the original asker.  Are you willing to do server side functionality for this?  If not, I think your question is invalid for a universal solution.